# Convert .tiff image to .png/.jpg in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, tiff

I have a .tiff format image and i want to convert it into .jpg or .png format.

I extract images from pdf using https://www.convertapi.com/ and i am getting some .tiff images that i want to convert to .png or .jpg because my device doesn’t open .tiff file.

I have tried the below code but it gives error.

```
 var dat = file.readAsBytesSync();

        imgLib.Image image = imgLib.decodeTiff(dat)!;
        print(image.data);
```

```
E/flutter ( 7774): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid uncompressed block header
E/flutter ( 7774): #0      Inflate._parseUncompressedBlock
package:archive/…/zlib/inflate.dart:198
E/flutter ( 7774): #1      Inflate._parseBlock
package:archive/…/zlib/inflate.dart:116
E/flutter ( 7774): #2      Inflate._inflate
package:archive/…/zlib/inflate.dart:92
E/flutter ( 7774): #3      new Inflate
package:archive/…/zlib/inflate.dart:16
E/flutter ( 7774): #4      TiffImage._decodeTile
package:image/…/tiff/tiff_image.dart:314
E/flutter ( 7774): #5      TiffImage.decode
package:image/…/tiff/tiff_image.dart:232
E/flutter ( 7774): #6      TiffDecoder.decodeImage
package:image/…/formats/tiff_decoder.dart:63
E/flutter ( 7774): #7      decodeTiff
package:image/…/formats/formats.dart:290
E/flutter ( 7774): #8      PDFTools.pdfToImages.<anonymous closure>
package:pdf_manager/Controller/Tools.dart:153
E/flutter ( 7774): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

as said in this question's answer ([How to display a TIFF image in a Flutter app on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030936/how-to-display-a-tiff-image-in-a-flutter-app-on-an-android-device))

```
 /// This only accepts compressed image formats (e.g. PNG). Uncompressed
  /// formats like rawRgba (the default format of [dart:ui.Image.toByteData])
  /// will lead to exceptions.
```

and i think the tiff file you are providing is uncompressed so your code is throwing exception.

Comment: Ah, I saw that answer but missed that point. Thank You brother. You saved my day